# Integrate the following with respect to $x$.

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate the given:
$$\int 3x\sqrt {x+5} dx$$.

My Attempt:
$$\int 3x\sqrt {x+5} dx$$
$$3\int x\sqrt {x+5} dx$$

What should I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u-substitution!

Let $u=(x+5)^{1/2}$ so that $du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+5}}dx$, or $2udu=dx$. Then your integral is given by
\begin{align*}
I&=3\int (u^2-5)u2udu\\
&=6\int u^4-5u^2du\\
&=\frac{6}{5}u^5-10u^2+C\\
&=\frac{6}{5}(x+5)^{\frac{5}{2}}-10(x+5)^\frac{3}{2}+C
\end{align*}

Comment: why / how is 
$$du=\dfrac {1}{2\sqrt {x+5}} dx$$???

Comment: @Ramanujan That's what happens when you take the derivative of the function $u(x)=\sqrt{x+5}$. You get $du/dx=1/(2\sqrt{x+5}$

Answer (score 1):

Set $u=x+5$, so the integrand becomes $3(u-5)\sqrt{u} = 3u^{3/2}-15u^{1/2}.$  (And here $dx=du$.)  In general, square roots and addition don't get along well together, so when you see $\sqrt{a\pm b}$, you can make the difficulty go away by substituting $u=a \pm b.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: rationalize by taking $u = \sqrt{x+5}$.

Alternatively, and perhaps even simpler:
$$x\sqrt{x+5} = \left(x+5-5\right)\sqrt{x+5} = \left(x+5\right)^{3/2}-5\left(x+5\right)^{1/2}$$
So:
$$\int x\sqrt{x+5} \,\mbox{d}x = \int \left(x+5\right)^{3/2} \,\mbox{d}x -5\int \left(x+5\right)^{1/2} \,\mbox{d}x  = \ldots$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Take $x+5=t^2$. Then the integral reduces to $$3\int (t^2-5)t 2t dt=6\int t^4-5t^2 $$

Comment: @Why is $x+5$ to be considered as $t^2$ ,but not only $t$?

Comment: You can take it to be $t$. Then it will involve integrating fractions which is okay too.

Answer (score 0):

Or it can be used the integration by parts:

$u = x, dv=\sqrt{x+5}dx \Rightarrow du=dx,v=\frac{2}{3}(x+5)^{\frac{3}{2}}.$

$\int 3x\sqrt{x+5}dx=3\left[x\cdot\frac{2}{3}(x+5)^{\frac{3}{2}}-\int\frac{2}{3}(x+5)^{\frac{3}{2}}dx \right]=2x(x+5)^{\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{4}{5}(x+5)^{\frac{5}{2}}+C=\frac{2}{5}(x+5)^{\frac{3}{2}}(5x-2(x+5))+C=\frac{2}{5}(x+5)^{\frac{3}{2}}(3x-10)+C$